# Specs on Siliconix SSTC34-T1

Tags: datasheet, surface-mount

I have been gifted about 2/3 of a reel (2000-ish) of these SOT-23 parts but I cannot locate any data for them.  Can anyone point me in the right direction.

Through the various datasheet sites I have determined that they are probably an N channel JFet that was obsoleted in 2007.  The local dealer in siliconix products was unable (or unwilling) to help.

the label on the reel reads:

```
        SILICONIX
17856             SSTC34-T1
G45004  (E10)     E9612
QA D/C Q9613E     QTY 3000
PHILIPPINES       30 MAR 96
```

The case marking on these is C34

Answer (score 2):

A tough problem... it's very annoying that manufacturers "unpublish" their datasheets. I have had to go down this road, and I would recommend calling up the manufacturer's rep (Vishay Siliconix) and ask them if they can provide a datasheet.

**edit:** just noticed you mentioned the local siliconix dealer was unwilling to help. Do you mean a distributor or a sales rep? I'd get on the phone with someone (sales rep or tech support) direct from Vishay. If they still don't help, let us know; it's good to share pluses and minuses about various IC / component companies.

Comment: I spoke to someone at Arrow Electronics in Perth.  They are listed on the Vishay web site as a local distributor.

I haven't been able to find an email address of anyone at Vishay who looks like they'd be able to help.  I guess they don't do that by mistake.